# adding a search box / text field to android's header bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

In one activity of my app, I use android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar for the header bar. By default, the header bar layout consists of

1. ImageButton "navigation drawer" in the left most
2. TextView header bar's title
3. Menu items in the right most

I'm trying to do:

- set title to "", so basically the title won't take any space
- add an element X (e.g., some sort of text input / search box) between "navigation drawer" and existing menu items such that this element will take full space between 1 and 3.

I tried to add X to menu items but I can't set its width to remaining space in header bar. I guess I probably have to manually modify the header bar layout instead of adding X to menu items. Eventhough, I still don't know how to make this element automatically take full remaining space between 1 and 3. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Look into using the AppBarLayout xml element

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. set title to "", so basically the title won't take any space.

For this you don't need to set title to "" just call

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

2. add an element X (e.g., some sort of text input / search box) between "navigation drawer" and existing menu items such that this element will take full space between 1 and 3.

For this you need to edit menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".ui.activities.UserListActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:title="@string/menu_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default"/>
</menu>
```

and in activity you have to write code :-

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_user_list, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            //TODO write your code what you want to perform on search                
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            //TODO write your code what you want to perform on search text change                
            return true;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

You don't need to add X icon manually it is handle by android itself. Once you click on search icon it will open edit text with cross icon on header and once you will click on cross the header will automatically gets shrink.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding a `SearchView` in your menu items

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

      <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
            android:title="Search"
            app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
            app:showAsAction="always"/>

      <!-- other menu items -->
</menu>
```

Then in your activity use the `setIconifiedByDefault()` to false so the search field is always shown:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    return true;
 }
```